# Less CSS can't resolve fonts URL in Webpack

Tags: css, webpack, less, bundling-and-minification, webpack-style-loader

I have a large Backbone.JS code base we are moving to be built with webpack so we can move to a traditional React/Redux app. We are trying to do very little changes to the source code. We want Webpack to resolve as much as possible before we have to refactor.

However, I'm having local URL resolution fail in my CSS.

I've tried the `resolve-URL-loader` but that kept getting more complicated as it required PostCSS which came with its own problems not understanding some of our LESS code convention.

Error:

```
~/Code/main/base/project/frontend on  webpack! ⌚ 14:58:22
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
Hash: adfc7f2dc8f413ebcf17
Version: webpack 4.44.1
Time: 8386ms
Built at: 08/03/2020 2:58:33 PM
 71 assets
Entrypoint frontend = frontend.js
 [0] ./client/cygnus.js 8.14 KiB {0} [built]
 [4] ./client/os/collections/risk-profiles.js 350 bytes {1} [built]
 [5] ./client/os/collections/lanes.js 2.77 KiB {1} [built]
 [6] ./client/os/lib/app-time.js 1.73 KiB {4} [built]
 [7] ./client/os/collections/assets.js 1.74 KiB {1} [built]
 [8] ./client/os/collections/groups.js 1.83 KiB {1} [built]
 [9] ./client/os/views/spinner.js 2.05 KiB {1} [built]
[10] ./client/boot.js 445 bytes {4} [built]
[11] ./client/os/router.js 18.3 KiB {1} [built]
[12] ./client/os/models/map.js 708 bytes {1} [built]
[13] ./client/os/views/map.js 15.4 KiB {1} [built]
[14] ./client/os/views/header.js 7.06 KiB {1} [built]
[15] ./client/os/views/dock.js 11.7 KiB {1} [built]
[16] ./client/os/views/notification.js 2.15 KiB {1} [built]
[17] ./client/os/lib/set-active.js 1.43 KiB {1} [built]
    + 613 hidden modules

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:27:15
    at /Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
 @ ./client/cygnus.js 2:2-249:4
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!client/styles/cygnus.less:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
     [2] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less 388 KiB {0} [built]
     [3] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css 22.8 KiB {0} [built]
    [24] ./client/styles/fonts/league_gothic/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.woff 69 bytes {0} [built]
    [25] ./client/styles/fonts/league_gothic/leaguegothic-regular-webfont.ttf 68 bytes {0} [built]
    [26] ./client/styles/fonts/league_gothic/leaguegothic-italic-webfont.woff 69 bytes {0} [built]
    [27] ./client/styles/fonts/league_gothic/leaguegothic-italic-webfont.ttf 68 bytes {0} [built]
    [28] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff 69 bytes {0} [built]
    [29] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf 68 bytes {0} [built]
    [30] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff 69 bytes {0} [built]
    [31] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.ttf 68 bytes {0} [built]
    [32] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-extralight-webfont.woff 69 bytes {0} [built]
    [33] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-extralight-webfont.ttf 68 bytes {0} [built]
    [34] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.woff 69 bytes {0} [built]
    [35] ./client/styles/fonts/source_sans/sourcesanspro-bold-webfont.ttf 68 bytes {0} [built]
    [36] ./client/styles/fonts/cygnus-icons.eot?4mh43w 68 bytes {0} [built]
        + 55 hidden modules
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 14:36-88
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 18:37-89
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 17:37-89
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 16:37-90
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 15:37-91
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../vendor/pulse/img/select2-spinner.gif' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 20:37-87
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../vendor/pulse/img/select2.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 19:37-79
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/layers-2x.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 6:36-69
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/layers.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 5:36-66
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/marker-icon.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 7:36-71
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/spritesheet-2x.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 10:36-74
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/spritesheet.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 8:36-71
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/spritesheet.svg' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 9:36-71
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './select2-spinner.gif' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 12:36-68
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './select2.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 11:36-60
    
    ERROR in ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './select2x2.png' in '/Users/stcalica/Code/main/base/project/frontend/client/styles'
     @ ./client/styles/cygnus.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./client/styles/cygnus.less) 13:36-62
```

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const frontend = path.resolve(__dirname, "client/os");
const vendor = path.resolve(__dirname, "client/vendor");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.(css|less)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: url => '/static/styles/' + url
            }
          },
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[hash].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'dist/sunrise/static/fonts/',
              publicPath: url => '/static/fonts/' + url
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|jpg|gif|png)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[hash].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'dist/sunrise/static/img/',
              publicPath: url => '/static/img/' + url
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: 'jQuery'
          },
          {
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: '$'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('backgrid'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: 'Backgrid'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  entry: {
    frontend: "./client/cygnus.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/sunrise/"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/static/sunrise/"
  },
  resolve: {
        alias: {
      'os': frontend,
      'styles': path.resolve(__dirname, "client/styles"),
      'boot': path.resolve(__dirname, "client/boot"),
      'templates': path.resolve(frontend, 'templates'),
      'backgrid-itemdata-cell': path.resolve(frontend, 'lib/backgrid-itemdata-cell'),
      'backgrid-pulse': path.resolve(vendor, 'pulse/backgrid'),
      'd3tip': path.resolve(vendor, 'pulse/d3tip'),
      'd3.radial': path.resolve(frontend, 'lib/d3.radial'),
      'jquery-ui': path.resolve(vendor, 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui'),
      'jquery-range-slider': path.resolve(vendor, 'jquery-ui/jq-range-slider'),
      'leaflet-antimeridian': path.resolve(vendor, 'leaflet/leaflet.antimeridian-src'),
      'leaflet-cluster': path.resolve(vendor, 'leaflet/leaflet.markercluster'),
      'leaflet-imgtransform': path.resolve(vendor, 'leaflet/L.ImageTransform'),
      'leaflet-pulse': path.resolve(vendor, 'leaflet/L.Icon.Pulse'),
      'push': path.resolve(frontend, 'lib/push'),
      'slimscroll': 'jquery-slimscroll',
      'spinjs': 'spin.js',
      'typeahead': path.resolve(vendor, "pulse/typeahead"),
      'pubsub': 'pubsub-js',
      'momenttz': 'moment-timezone',
      'transit': 'jquery.transit',
      'leaflet-encoded': 'polyline-encoded',
      'leaflet-geometry': 'leaflet-geometryutil',
      'leaflet-terminator': '@joergdietrich/leaflet.terminator',
      'jquery-file-upload': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload',
      'jquery.ui.widget': 'blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget',
      'datetimepicker': 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker',
      'daterangepicker': 'bootstrap-daterangepicker',
      'jquery-hammer': 'jquery-hammerjs',
      'bootstrap-treeview': 'patternfly-bootstrap-treeview',
      'backgrid-moment': 'backgrid-moment-cell',
      'crossfilter': 'crossfilter2',
      '$': path.resolve(vendor, 'pulse/jquery'),
        }
    }
};
```